# A ZFC-example of a countably compact paratopological group which is not a topological group

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups, compactness

> **Problem.** Does there exist a ZFC-example of a countably compact Hausdorff paratopological group which is not a topological group?

(The problem posed 27 May 2015 by Alexander Ravsky on [page 9](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=0&page=9) of [Volume 0](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=0) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php)).

---

The current state of the problem is the following.

The example (which is also a free abelian group) exists (see Example 20 in [BR]) provided there exists an infinite torsion-free Abelian countably compact topological group without non-trivial convergent sequences. The first example of such a group constructed by Tkachenko under the Continuum Hypothesis [Tka]. Later, the Continuum Hypothesis weakened  to the Martin Axiom for $\sigma$-centered posets by Tomita in [Tom], for countable posets in [KTW], and finally to the existence continuum many incomparable selective ultrafilters in [MT]. Yet, the problem of the existence of a countably compact group without convergent sequences in ZFC seems to be open, see [DS].

On the other hand, the required example $G$ should have the following properties. It is not quasiregular, not saturated, not topologically periodic, not left-omega perecompact [BR, Proposition 14], does not contain a compact non-empty $G_\delta$ subset [BR, Proposition 27],  contains a cyclic subroup whose closure is not a group [BR, Proposition 31], and the group $G\times G$ is not countably compact [RR, Propostion 3].

*References*

[BR] Taras Banakh, Alex Ravsky, “[On feebly compact paratopological groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5343)”, version 6.

[DS] D. Dikranjan, D. Shakhmatov, *Selected topics in the structure theory of topological groups*,
in: Open Problems in  Topology, II (E. Pearl ed.), Elsevier, 2007, 389-406.

[KTW] P. B. Koszmider, A. H. Tomita and S. Watson, *Forcing countably compact group topologies on a larger free Abelian group*, Topology Proc. **25** (2000), 563-574.

[MT] R. Madariaga-Garcia, A. H. Tomita, * Countably compact topological group topologies on free Abelian groups from selective ultrafilters*, Topology Appl. **154** (2007), 1470-1480.

[RR] A. Ravsky, E. A. Reznichenko, *The continuity of inverse in groups*, International Conference on Functional Analysis and its Applications Dedicated to the 110th anniversary of Stefan Banach, Book
of Abstracts, May 28-31, 2002, Lviv, 170-172.

[Tka] M. Tkachenko, *Countably compact and pseudocompact topologies on free Abelian groups*, Soviet Math. (Iz. VUZ) **34**:5 (1990), 79-86.

[Tom] A. H. Tomita, *The Wallace Problem: a counterexample from $MA_{countable}$ and $p$-compactness*, Canadian Math. Bulletin. **39** (4) (1996), 486-498.

Comment: What, no prizes on this one?

Comment: This is Problem 2.4.1 on p128 in the recent book Topological Groups and Related Structures by Arhangel'skij and Tkachenko. In the preceding section of the book it is shown that a *regular* Hausdorff countably compact paratopological group is a topological group. Also, a *pseudocompact* Hausdorff paratopological group is a topological group. Plus related results. Ravsky has published an example in 2003 under MA, hence the question.